# Remove Archive | from Categories

Tags: categories, css

Can Archive | be removed from the title of each category, either by CSS or core code change?

At the moment it shows as "Archive | My Category Name", I just wish it to show as "My Category Name"

I have tried with CSS, but no joy with

```
   .archive_header ["Archive |"] {
    display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are referring to the title shown in the browser title bar: this could be achieved by coding, but the easiest way would probably be to use an option provided by the SEO plugin Yoast (in case you have that installed).

In your admin go to "*SEO > Titles & Metas > Post Types*" – then at the end of that settings page you can choose a pattern for the Archive pages.

[image]

PS: In case you are instead referring to the actual page title, you can change or actually override that by copying the archives template `archive.php` to your child theme and then editing that.

If you find "Archives" added to your page title in the template then most probably the template adds that to the category term. In Twenty Twelve the respective code looks like this:

```
<h1 class="archive-title"><?php
    if ( is_day() ) :
        printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' );
        elseif ( is_month() ) :
        printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'twentytwelve' ) ) . '</span>' );
        elseif ( is_year() ) :
        printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'twentytwelve' ) ) . '</span>' );
        else :
        _e( 'Archives', 'twentytwelve' );
    endif;
?></h1>
```

…but in your theme this will probably look different, hence the title structure you described. It's difficult to say without knowing what theme you use and/or what your templates look like. I hope this helped anyways to digg in the right direction.

Comment: No it is the title of the category page, within the content

Comment: I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Why would you install a plugin to take care of something this simple????

Comment: Well – as I wrote in my post: ***if*** the OP was referring to the title shown in the browser title bar and ***if*** he/she had that plugin already installed ***then*** my first suggestion would be probably the easiest. But both seems not to be the case. I actually did not recommend to *install* a plugin – just to *use* it if it was already installed.